# plentymarkets add product via soap

Tags: soap

im trying to insert product to plentymarkets via soap, but i get this error : 
object(stdClass)#14 (2) { ["Success"]=> bool(false) ["ResponseMessages"]=> object(stdClass)#18 (0) { } }
here is my code

```
$client = new SoapClient($soapUrl);
         $aHeader           =   array(
            'UserID'    =>  '12',
            'Token'     =>  'ece85f3bc7a2783b164bf18ed882b6d6' //etcimport
        );

        $auth_vals          =   new SoapVar($aHeader, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
        $ns                 =   "Authentification";
        $oSoapHeader        =   new SoapHeader($ns,'verifyingToken', $auth_vals, false);
        $client = new SoapClient($soapUrl);
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($oSoapHeader);
        $result = $client->AddItemsBase(array(
            'ItemNo' => 123,
            'ExternalItemID' => 345,
            'EAN1' => 4011200296908
        ));
        var_dump($result);
```

Comment: If you work on version 7 switch to REST. As I remember you got wrong structure. It hast to be BaseItems->item[]->{your_array}. You have to wrap it with array with index BaseItems with index item which is array of your query.

Comment: oh thank you, it was over a year ago. i solved the problem, it turns out i didnt know how to use soap correctly, but i cant recall exactly how i did it.